# Document automation

Tags: python, node.js, automation, ms-word

I am trying to automate few repetitive tasks in Microsoft word document.
I have few Microsoft word documents where we check that the document follows certain guidelines for example fonts should be calibri, indentation for sub texts should start with bullets, any images should be bordered etc this I am checking manually by comparing the document.
need a suggestion on how can I automate this task ? are there any open source tools available for this or if this can be solved by Python/Nodejs programming approach (if yes any approach details will be great).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use python for this kind of task, node.js seems to be too much overhead.

A quick Google search returned a couple of results that might be helpful:

- https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx
- https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/